# Error "OGR: Unsupported geometry type" when using st_as_sfc from sf package in R

Tags: r, coordinates, geo, r-sf

Can anyone explain/troubleshoot this "OGR: Unsupported geometry type" error when using sf::st_as_sfc in R?

We have a text string version of something that was a geometry column in a sf. It's been exported and reimported. Reimporting and applying st_as_sfc to the geometry column used to work fine (a few months ago) - now it doesn't. Short reprex:

```
geos <- c("c(-3.287652, -3.28373, -3.280022, -3.279113, 55.87266, 55.87104, 55.86949, 55.86849)", "c(-3.239873, -3.239752, 55.87809, 55.87804)")
st_as_sfc(geos)

#> OGR: Unsupported geometry type
#> Error in CPL_sfc_from_wkt(x) : OGR errorenter code here
```

*Thanks in advance for any help & being gentle with me as a first-time stackexchange poster!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your input data is that they are not represented using a standard and unambiguous format. I want to propose the following solution. First, load package

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
```

then create input data

```r
geos <- c(
  "c(-3.287652, -3.28373, -3.280022, -3.279113, 55.87266, 55.87104, 55.86949, 55.86849)", 
  "c(-3.239873, -3.239752, 55.87809, 55.87804)"
)
```

Extract and format points

```r
geos_points <- sapply(geos, function(x) st_multipoint(matrix(eval(str2lang(x)), ncol = 2)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Print

```r
geos_points
#> [[1]]
#> MULTIPOINT ((-3.287652 55.87266), (-3.28373 55.87104), (-3.280022 55.86949), (-3.279113 55.86849))
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> MULTIPOINT ((-3.239873 55.87809), (-3.239752 55.87804))
```

Combine as an `sfc` object (you may want to add a CRS)

```r
st_as_sfc(geos_points)
#> Geometry set for 2 features 
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -3.287652 ymin: 55.86849 xmax: -3.239752 ymax: 55.87809
#> CRS:           NA
#> MULTIPOINT ((-3.287652 55.87266), (-3.28373 55....
#> MULTIPOINT ((-3.239873 55.87809), (-3.239752 55...
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I think that the solution is a little unorthodox (and you may want to wait for other answers), but it seems that it works!