# Converting character class to Spatial point

Tags: r, geospatial, ogr

I have a data frame in R, with some coordinates in EPSG 25832 system. I have tried some different things to convert the class to a spatial point, but I can't get it to work.

| Geometri_EPSG_25832 | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| POINT (549611.77 6189284.79) | 1.99 | 739 |
| POINT (700990.83 6223807.37) | 12 | 129 |

I have then tried something from another post:
[Error "OGR: Unsupported geometry type" when using st_as_sfc from sf package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67212607/error-ogr-unsupported-geometry-type-when-using-st-as-sfc-from-sf-package-in-r)

```
 # Remove "POINT" and parentheses
    Total_df$EPSG <- gsub("POINT|\\(|\\)", "", Total_df$Geometri_EPSG_25832)
    Total_df$EPSG <- sf::st_as_sfc(Total_df$EPSG,CRS("+init=epsg:25832"))
    
    
    # Convert to numeric values
    Total_df$x_coord <- as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(Total_df$EPSG, "[^ ]+"))
    Total_df$y_coord <- as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(Total_df$EPSG, "(?<=\\s)[^\\s]+"))
    Total_df$Coor <- paste0(Total_df$x_coord,", ", Total_df$y_coord)
    Total_df$geos_points <- sapply(Total_df$Coor, function(x) st_multipoint(matrix(eval(str2lang(x)), ncol = 2)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

But then  get an:
Error in parse(text = x) : :1:10: unexpected ','
1: 549611.77,
^

Answer (score 2):

Your dataframe seems to have a geometry in [Well-known text format (WKT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry). `sf` is supporting that format.

I just saw the answer of margusl. I think that we can do everything in the same `st_as_sf` call.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.7.2, PROJ 9.3.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

df =data.frame(  Geometri_EPSG_25832 = c("POINT (549611.77 6189284.79)" ,
                                     "POINT (700990.83 6223807.37)"),
             Var1 = c(1.99,12) , Var2 = c(739,129))
             

st_as_sf(df, wkt="Geometri_EPSG_25832", crs = 25832 )
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 549611.8 ymin: 6189285 xmax: 700990.8 ymax: 6223807
#> Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
#>    Var1 Var2      Geometri_EPSG_25832
#> 1  1.99  739 POINT (549611.8 6189285)
#> 2 12.00  129 POINT (700990.8 6223807)
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-20 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: We sure can and there's also less clutter in resulting sf object. Thanks fo the reminder that there's also `wkt=...` :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your responses.
When I run it, I get an error: 
OGR: Unsupported geometry type
Error: OGR error

Could it be to the data? When I skim through it all observations are of the same form: POINT (549611.77 6189284.79) but I have more than 2mil observations

Comment: It is hard to say without additionnal informatin. My first suggestion would be to verify if there is other geometry than points (ex. polygones, linestrings...). Maybe try to `st_as_sf` on the `head` of `df` (taking the first rows)

Comment: @VinceGreg Didn't know how to tag you in 'answer', but thank you and all other suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

@VinceGreg, but your suggestion was the missing piece. I thank you very much. I ran Total_df$Coor[!grepl("^POINT", Total_df$Coor)] to detect if any observations started without "POINT", then made sure it all had the same format, and then I could apply st_as_sfc with ease. Thank you!

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  It is a comment intended for another SO user.  It should be a comment.  That's what comments are for.